# Looking for a simple/minimal telnet chat service

Tags: server

I want to be able to patch through a port from my router to a simple telnet based chat service. By simple I mean low RAM and CPU footprint and easy to start using.

I want to allow anyone to connect and enter a username to start chatting with.

Comment: Looks like you have [a few choices](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=linux+telnet+chat+server).

Answer (score 1):

You could try `telnet-chatd`

Use:

```
sudo apt-get install telnet-chatd
```